# struture HTML form to create a array of objects using form data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js

hello I have a HTML form that's using the react [form action](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/form) using [form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

When extracting formData from my method its shows likes:

[image]

what im trying to achieve or my expectation is that I would get an array of objects:

```json
  "completeSuccessIndicators": [
    {
    "si": 1,
    "actual_accomplishment": "this the acutal accomplishmentsasdfasdfas",
    "ql_qn": 1,
    "timeliness": 3,
    "average": 3,
    "remarks": "asdfasdf"
    },
    {
    "si": 2,
    "actual_accomplishment": "this the acutal 2222123123s",
    "ql_qn": 1,
    "timeliness": 3,
    "average": 3,
    "remarks": "another remarks"
    }
  ]
```

is there away for it to be automatic like PHP or Ruby on rails? or is there a package that I could use? as of right now I'm thinking of creating a logic to parse form data.

PS: I'm using nextjs for my react project.

Comment: You can set you property names directly `"completeSuccessIndicators"`, `fd.append("completeSuccessIndicators", JSON.stringify(completeSuccessIndicators))`, then set the value to the JavaScript plain object serialized to JSON, then use `JSON,parse(fd.get("completeSuccessIndicators"))` in the server.

Comment: hello. Thank you for your response. can you elaborate on this? so you mean I should append before creating the actual form? like `fd.append("comp...")` then, create the html form then after submission i can parse and get the data? but on the html form how should i add the names?

Comment: You can set the entire JSON string in one property, then use `JSON.parse()` server side to read that JSON as a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install Radash package with `npm i radash`. It's a more modern and lightweight replacement for Lodash.
2. Simply do:

```js
import { construct } from 'radash'

const formDataObject = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
const finalObject = construct(formDataObject)
```

The `finalObject` is what you need.

Alternatively, you can try using [Formik](https://formik.org/) or different libraries for building forms in React.

Comment: thank you for this. I just read the documentation. will mark this as answer if I fixed the issue but im sure it will. thank you for this. Im not planning on using `Formik` because this is just an MVP we are just trying this feature out so `radash` would be fine. thank you again.

Comment: This one works. thank you. appreciate the help.